# Android [lint] Enforce @nullable @nonnull in stylecheck/lint gradle task via code distribution

Tags: android, git, lint

How do I enforce @nullable and @nonnull for all methods in java code base and distribute it via scm (git) to all my team mates

Comment: You should use related settings for adding `@nullable` and `@nonnull` annotations (not git), you can refer the related document https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html.

Comment: I want to know if I could add this as a lint rule